# Calling Facebook login button from appbar

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, facebook-sdk-4.0

I implemented Facebook login button following the facebook SDK info, and it is working nicely.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,2,0,0" Height="70" width="430">
    <fbc:LoginButton x:Name="loginButton" Width="200" applicationId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" SessionStateChanged="OnSessionStateChanged"/>
</StackPanel>
```

However. I'd like to hide the blue button from the main view area and move it to the appbar. Can this be done somehow? My initial idea was to dig up the call login button makes when you click it and make this call from appbar button, but I can't find any info about the inner working of the login button.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can "in a way" implement it. The underlying concept is **calling an event from another event.** You need to carry out the following steps.

1.Set up the AppBar.

2.Give the AppBar button a unique suitable icon.

3.Call the Facebook Login Button's click event through the AppBar Button's click event.

```
    void appBarButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnSessionStateChanged(null,null); //Call the Facebook Log In Button's event here.
    }
```

I hope this somewhat solves your problem.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work. The Facebook login button uses some kind of hidden custom logic and doesn't use click or tap methods or events. That's why I asked how to do it.

Comment: The basic thing that I'm trying to convey is that **you can call an event from another event.** Try it with the OnSessionStateChanged thing. I've edited my answer accordingly.